# POST & GET - 302 Temp Moved

Tags: php, forms, get, request

I'm facing an odd issue with a form post to a 3rd party, my server is posting from https to https on the 3rd party, they then process and post back to me via 302. I see the callback but the submit post is 302 Moved Temporarily, which makes it impossible to $_GET, $_REQUEST, or $_POST which would be the usual methods I would use to get the passed variables from my own form. I see the 3rd party submission back from their server, passed as a string in an object. 
Suggestions on how to best approach this, or method would be most appreciated.

Regards
J.

Comment: have you asked to the 3rd party?

Comment: Yes, they claim a simple echo "{";
echo "item2: ", json_encode($GET_, "datasheet"), "<br>";
echo "}"; will retrieve the results.